# Storing comma-delimited data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've read that this is a no-no, but I'm wondering if this is ALWAYS the case.  I've got a list of "dining tables" that can accommodate an array of seats.
[image]

You can see in the image that table_num 12 will accommodate 2 OR 3 seats.

So, now my current solution is to query all the table records (according to the user_index for undisclosed reasons) then loop through the results looking for tables that can fit 3 people (if it happens to be three people looking for a table).

I do that by using the array_implode() method (in php) on the 'seats' column of my return data.  I feel like this is an easier solution than creating a separate 'seats' table and then assigning a table_index and user_index to each seating possibility, and then having to run a second query to find the table_num in the original 'tables' table.

Basically, by using array_implode() I am able to circumvent a second query.  But, I don't know if that is less taxing.  Or, possibly I am missing out on some awesome query language (like relational table lingo?)

Comment: Just curious. Why couldn't a table that seats 3 always be able to seat 2? In other words, why couldn't the column be called `max_seats`?

Comment: @webbiedave,  this isn't really a real world example.  The reason is there will be a table that seats 5 or 6 people but we don't want 2 people sitting there and a 'max_seats' would allot an unwanted number of people at that table.  There are also some other misc. circumstance with combined table numbers.

Comment: What happens if you want to find records that contain 10 in the combo field? And you don't need a second query if you hold the combo data in a second table, just a JOIN in your query

Comment: @MarkBaker,  That's a whole other can of worms!  But, yes, I am going to apply the answer of this question to that column as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you removed the `seats` column from this table and then had a new `seats` table with three columns: `id`, `table_index`, and `num_seats`, where `table_index` relates to `index` in your existing table (many-to-one as there may be multiple entires per table in `seats`). The you could select the tables you want like so:

```
SELECT tables.* FROM tables
INNER JOIN seats ON tables.index = seats.table_index
WHERE seats.num_seats = ?
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a table that's called something like `TableSeats`. In it, you'd have a `table_num` and a `seats` column. Use the `table_num` column as a foreign key. Then, to find tables that seat 3 people, it'd be like so:

```
select
    *
from
    tables t
where
    exists (select 1 from tableseats s where s.seats = 3)
```

The magic here is the `exists` clause. Certainly, you could also do an `inner join`, but I'd recommend `exists` here, because this allows you to find any tables that can seat at least 7 people by saying `where s.seats >= 7`, or even a table that can seat between 5 and 8 people with `where s.seats between 5 and 8`.

Comment: So, is the foreign key populated automatically?

Comment: @Jascha - Nope, all it does is it ensures that a value that's populated in `table_num` *has* to exist in your `Tables` table. You'll need to populate the table either manually or a one-time programmatic load.

Comment: It looks like the join method is best for this particular case.  There are instances where I wouldn't want to seat 2 people at a 6 person table.  I didn't mention that in my question... I feel bad but someone answered with the join method (and example) specifically so I feel like I have to give him the checkmark.  I am certainly giving you a point though.

Answer (score 4):

Correct me if I am wrong, but this does not sound a list. It is more like a range (like, from 2 up to 3 seats). So you could have a better structure by replacing the `seats` field by the fields `min_seats` and `max_seats`. The queries are straight forward then.

Comment: It's a good point, but in this particular case I'd prefer to keep it as a list (there could be circumstances where tables are joined etc...)

Comment: OK, then, go for a new table. If you wander when it's okay to store a list into one field, I would say that it's okay only if you don't want to run queries on top of that field. In your case, it really is a NO-NO :-)